# Cannot find or load main class inside a package

Tags: java, linked-list, package

I'm new to Java coming from Python and C and I am having trouble running this code. To compile I am using:

```
javac SLList.java
```

And to run I am using:

```
java SLList
```

Which is where I am getting the problem. I suspect the issue is that the code is inside a package and I must use a different running instruction. For reference the code is provided below:

```
package ods;

import java.util.AbstractQueue;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * An implementation of a FIFO Queue as a singly-linked list.
 * This also includes the stack operations push and pop, which
 * operate on the head of the queue
 * @author morin
 *
 * @param <T> the class of objects stored in the queue
 */
public class SLList<T> extends AbstractQueue<T> {
    class Node {
        T x;
        Node next;
    }

    /**
     * Front of the queue
     */
    Node head;

    /**
     * Tail of the queue
     */
    Node tail;

    /**
     * The number of elements in the queue
     */
    int n;

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        class SLIterator implements Iterator<T> {
            protected Node p;

            public SLIterator() {
                p = head;
            }
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return p != null;
            }
            public T next() {
                T x = p.x;
                p = p.next;
                return x;
            }
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }
        return new SLIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return n;
    }

    public boolean add(T x) {
        Node u = new Node();
        u.x = x;
        if (n == 0) {
            head = u;
        } else {
            tail.next = u;
        }
        tail = u;
        n++;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean offer(T x) {
        return add(x);
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        return head.x;
    }

    public T poll() {
        if (n == 0)
            return null;
        T x = head.x;
        head = head.next;
        if (--n == 0)
            tail = null;
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Stack push operation - push x onto the head of the list
     * @param x the element to push onto the stack
     * @return x
     */
    public T push(T x) {
        Node u = new Node();
        u.x = x;
        u.next = head;
        head = u;
        if (n == 0)
            tail = u;
        n++;
        return x;
    }

    protected void deleteNext(Node u) {
        if (u.next == tail)
            tail = u;
        u.next = u.next.next;
    }

    protected void addAfter(Node u, Node v) {
        v = u.next.next;
        u.next = v;
        if (u == tail) 
            tail = v;
    }

    protected Node getNode(int i) {
        Node u = head;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            u = u.next;
        return u;
    }

    /**
     * Stack pop operation - pop off the head of the list
     * @return the element popped off 
     */
    public T remove() {
        if (n == 0) return null;
        T x = head.x;
        head = head.next;
        if (--n == 0) tail = null;
        return x;
    }   

    public T pop() {
        if (n == 0) return null;
        T x = head.x;
        head = head.next;
        if (--n == 0) tail = null;
        return x;
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new SLList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            q.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(q);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            q.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(q);
        for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
            q.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(q);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            q.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(q);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            q.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(q);

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first compile it from outside the package and then run from there also. e.g.

```
javac ods/SLList.java
```

Then

```
java ods.SLList
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem